# Get all products with a custom attribute

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I want do a custom query to get all products with an especific attribute ("demo" in my case)
The query what i want returns from this:

```
a:5:{s:4:"demo";
a:6:{s:4:"name";
    s:4:"DEMO";
    s:5:"value";
    s:366:"LINK TO DEMO";
    s:8:"position";
    s:1:"0";
    s:10:"is_visible";
    i:0;
    s:12:"is_variation";
    i:0;
    s:11:"is_taxonomy";
    i:0;
}
```

}

I don't know how do an $args to get products. I want $args be something like this:

```
    $args = array ( 
         'meta_query' => array( 
             array( 
              'key' => 'meta_value', 
              'value' => 'demo', 
              'compare' => 'LIKE', ), 
           ), 
   );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I HAVE ALREADY!! yuhuuu!

Thanks a lot guys!!

I have this:

```
$args = array ( 
     'post_type'  => 'product',
     'posts_per_page'  => -1,
     'meta_query' => array( 
         array( 
          'value' => 'demo', 
          'compare' => 'like'
         ), 
       ),
     );
```

Well this works at least for me

Thanks thanks!!

Best regards!

Comment: Just for someone looking similar solution, this code will not work for most of the cases. It might have worked for specific situation.

Answer (score 3):

You have written `key` as `meta_value`. It should be your meta name. The name you have given to your custom fields or meta. Then use the following query.

```
$args = array ( 
         'post_type'  => 'your-post-type',
         'posts_per_page'  => -1,
         'meta_query' => array( 
             array( 
              'key' => 'demo', 
              'value' => '',
              'compare' => '!='
             ), 
           ), 
   );
```

By default the `compare` is set to `=`

Comment: Thanks, i want get all products if have an attribute called 'demo', i wont get value because value's field will be a link
Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @user2879109 I updated the code. Please check

Comment: No, i tried and doesn't work for me. In my wp_postmeta.meta_value i have this:

a:5:{
 s:4:"demo";
 a:6:{s:4:"name";
  s:4:"DEMO";
  s:5:"value";
  s:366:"LINK TO DEMO";
  s:8:"position";
  s:1:"0";
  s:10:"is_visible";
  i:0;
  s:12:"is_variation";
  i:0;
  s:11:"is_taxonomy";
  i:0;
 }
 ... more attributes
}

Comment: in any of your post where you have that demo key. Can you do a `get_post_meta(get_the_ID());` and show the returned array.

Comment: I got it, thanks for your help!! i wrote the code below

Comment: meta_key that stores woocommerce attributes is '_product_attributes'. Still there is no specific way to search product based on custom product attributes.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
$args = array(
    "post_type" => "product",
    "meta_query" => array(
        array(
            "key"     => "demo",
            "value" => "abc",
            "compare" => "EXISTS",
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thanks but im still getting 0 results

Comment: add "value" => "abc", next to "key" and "compare". the doc speak about a possible bug but it's not clear for me if you need "value" or not (I modified the code above)

Comment: I got it, your code and karun's code help so much!
Thanks.

Comment: meta_key that stores woocommerce attributes is '_product_attributes'. Still there is no specific way to search product based on custom product attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but straight sql, here are my solutions:

Get all meta data for a product:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = 626
```

Get products with specific meta data

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title, m.meta_key, m.meta_value FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.id=m.post_id AND m.meta_key='_auction_dates_to'
```

APPEND TO GET META DATA FOR A SPECIFIC PRODUCT

```
AND p.id=626
```

Append to get specific meta value

```
AND m.meta_value='today'
```